# Illegal start of type error in method declaration

Tags: java

Can someone please explain to me why I am still getting the following error? I'm trying to include a calculation of the commission.

```
  illegal start of type public static void GalleryCommission("Price * .20"
```

Here is my code:

```
            import java.util.Scanner;
            import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

            public class Painting {

            private static Object paintingTitle;
        private static Object artist;
        private static Object medium;
        private static Object price;
        private static Oblect GalleryCommission;

        public static void main(String[] args){

    String result;
    result = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "What is Paint Title?"); 
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Paint Title is " + result + "!");
    result = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "What is Artist name?");
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Artist is " + result + "!");
    result = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "What is Medium?");
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Medium is " + result + "!");
    result = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "What is Price?");
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Price is $" + result + "!");
    result = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "To Calculate Gallery Commission Price is?");
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "GalleryCommission is $" + "result *.20");
}

public static Object getPrice() {
    return price;
}
public static void setPrice(Object price) {
   return ObjectPrice;
  }
    public static void GalleryCommission("Price * .20") {
    return GalleryCommission;
}  
 }
```

Comment: Could you rename your question so that the title describes the problem somehow, please?

Comment: Your use of 'Object' is bugging me. Java is strongly typed.

Comment: I want each item to pop up, take input and display it. However, on the last one I want it to return the commission but not outside of the class. Each field should have a constrictor that displays default values and then at the end will explain the commission rate.

Answer (score 4):

There are a few problems with your method.

```
public static void GalleryCommission("Price * .20") {
    return GalleryCommission;
}
```

It is a `void` method but has a `return` statement.

---

The arguments are wrongly specified. It must be like this

```
public static void GalleryCommission(DataType argName) {
```

Ex:

```
public static void GalleryCommission(Object price) {
```

---

Also, if you want to return `GalleryCommission` then change your method signature to something like this

```
public static Object GalleryCommission() { // Note that I did not give any argument.
    return GalleryCommission;
}
```

---

There is a typo in this line

```
private static Oblect GalleryCommission; // Oblect is not a valid data type
```

It has to be

```
private static Object GalleryCommission; // Object
```

Answer (score 0):

remove the `"Price * .20"` your method contains return statement,remove the `void` and change to the

Object type

```
 public static Object GalleryCommission() {
        return GalleryCommission;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many things wrong with your method `GalleryCommission`,

```
public static void GalleryCommission("Price * .20") {
  return GalleryCommission;
}
```

First, you can't return a value from a `void` method. Second, you can't pass a `String` literal as an argument like that. Finally, you should use the Java naming convention. With that in mind,  I think you wanted,

```
private static double COMMISSION = 0.2;
public static double getGalleryCommission(double price) {
  return price * COMMISSION;
}
```

Comment: Thank you all, I will look at all the options. I am doing this as a hobby(trying to learn). I wasn't sure if the method was correct. As for "Object", I think Eclipse suggested that. I am trying both compilers, Eclipse and jGrasp.